# get the value from the object from the iteration of the item in the list

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

The below is my Javascript code where I am iterating the List `lstOfValues`, and access the appropriate value from the object of `caseVal` where the key is present iterating item in the list.

For example: I am iterating the `lstOfValues` and the present item in the list is `'Name__c'` and I want to get the value of `caseVal['Name__c']` in `HTML`

**Javascript file:**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
    export default class Jsontest extends LightningElement {
        @track lstOfValues = ['Name__c', 'Home__c'];
        @track caseVal = { 'Name__c': 'Rahul', 'Home__c':'Manikonda'}; 
    }
```

**HTML file:**

```
<template>
    <template for:each={lstOfValues} for:item="cae">
        <p key={cae}> {cae} {caseVal.cae} </p>
    </template>
</template>
```

**Output of the above HTML file is:**

```
Name__c
Home__c
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
Name__c Rahul
Home__c Manikonda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arut said, you're trying to access the property `cae` of `caseVal`, that is undefined, so you see nothing.
Since you want to show a paired values (apiName - value), you should build an object according to this requirement, an object with two properties, then you should expose to the template a list of such object.
In order to build the single object you have to loop on `caseVal`'s keys, so you could use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and get the related value via the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

If you want to display every property of `caseVal` you don't need `lstOfValues`:

```js
caseVal = { 'Name__c': 'Rahul', 'Home__c': 'Manikonda' }; 

get casePropertyList() {
    const propertyList = [];
    for (const key in this.caseVal) {
        const property = {
            key,
            value: this.caseVal[key]
        };
        propertyList.push(property);
    }
    return propertyList;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <template for:each={casePropertyList} for:item="property">
        <p key={property.key}> {property.key} {property.value} </p>
    </template>
</template>
```

Of course instead of providing a getter for `casePropertyList` you could build it as soon as you retrieve `caseVal`.

Instead, if you want to display every property of `caseVal` that is listed in `lstOfValues`, you could simply filter the key of `caseVal`:

```js
lstOfValues = ['Name__c', 'Home__c'];
caseVal = { 'Name__c': 'Rahul', 'Home__c': 'Manikonda', 'Status': 'Open' }; 

get filteredCasePropertyList() {
    const propertyList = [];
    for (const key in this.caseVal) {
        if (this.lstOfValues.includes(key))
            const property = {
                key,
                value: this.caseVal[key]
            };
            propertyList.push(property);
        }
    }
    return propertyList;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <template for:each={filteredCasePropertyList} for:item="property">
        <p key={property.key}> {property.key} {property.value} </p>
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this code in HTML file `{caseVal.cae}`, LWC literally tries to look for a property `cae` within the object `caseVal` which doesn't exist. And, computed expressions like  `caseVal['Name__c']` are not yet allowed in LWC.

You will have to use CSS to display the data in the format you need them. Or, you will have format the data structure in JS to make it easily usable in the LWC HTML.